# The meanings of proverbs and adages

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the meaning of a adage and a proverb.It is really confusing.I am just wondering the meanings of both of them.

Comment: They mean basically the same thing.  I don't think there's any significant difference in meaning or reason that a particular saying would be assigned to one category vs the other.

Answer (score 2):

Their principal meanings as given in the OED are very similar and cross-refer. My own sense is that to call something a *proverb* is to give it a slightly higher moral tone than might be implied by *adage*, possibly because of association with the Book of Proverbs in the Bible.

***Proverb*** A short, traditional, and pithy saying; a concise sentence, typically metaphorical or alliterative in form, stating a general truth or piece of advice; an adage or maxim.

***Adage*** A traditional maxim; a proverb or short statement expressing a general truth.

Comment: I agree. Note that the def for _proverb_ includes  "advice".  So, IMO "shit happens", or "you can't win 'em all" might better be called adages than proverbs, even though they express general truths.  Of course, there are plenty of verses in Proverbs that don't (explicitly) offer advice, either.  Maybe they've just been considered classier by virtue of the King James – era English.